# Complex integral along an ellipse

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to evaluate the function $f(z)$ = (1+$e^z$/$z^2$) along the ellipse $cos(t)$+2$i$$sin(t)$ where t goes from 0 to 2$\pi$. I know there's singularity at 0. I am thinking of using a homotopy from this ellipse to a circle but I don't know how to write it down.  If there's a simpler way without using homotopy, please point it out. Any help with this integral is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Look at the region between the ellipse and the circle. Your function is analytic in that region. Use Cauchy's Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have noted that the only singularity occurs at $z=0$ which is contained in your contour. If you have access to the residue theorem you can use it here. The value of the integral is $2\pi i$ times the coefficient on the $1/z$ term of the Laurent series.

Rewriting your function as
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}e^z=1/z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}(1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+.....)
$$
We see the only term that gives weight to the integral has coefficient 1, so the value is just $2\pi i$.

Comment: @Hades sure thing!